# Hide overflowing paragraphs in div of undefined size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container div, with absolute position whose dimensions are defined by percentages of the viewport (via a few parent elements), i.e. the height is given by `div {top:15%; bottom:10%}`. The width is likewise defined.

I would like this div to contain text which fills the whole area without ridiculous spacings, comprising a certain number of "compulsory" paragraphs, followed by several "optional" paragraphs if there is space. The idea is that it would be arranged so that the maximum number of whole paragraphs will be displayed, and then spaced evenly to fill the div. If necessary I can have a scrolling overflow as a fall back, but I would prefer not to. I only want to include the additional information (which may include graphics) if there is space, and not to present an essay on a small screen that needs to be scrolled through.

Any ideas for a solution with CSS and/or javascript?

Comment: With media queries, you could hide or display elements based on screen dimensions

Comment: I could, although I'd be concerned that browser height would be too variable for that to be practical. I'd prefer the selection to be more dynamic.

But if there's no better way I could give it a go.

Comment: Take a look at it, you can set a few different breakpoints allowing some adjustment. I'd be delighted to give you further insight, but my bed is calling me. And the magic of media queries will provide you with solutions I'm sure :-p